# Error in an iterator for a deque

Tags: c++, iterator, deque

```
int CardDeck::inOrder(){
    deque<int>::const_iterator i;
    for (i = nameofdeque.begin(); i != nameofdeque.end(); ++i){ 
            if (nameofdeque[i] >= nameofdeque[i+1]){
            return 0;
        }
    }   
    return 1;
 }
```

This code gives an error on the 4th line saying "CardDeck.cpp:37: error: expected type-specifier before '[' token
CardDeck.cpp:37:: Too many arguments.

I am wondering how to  fix this.
I tried "if(nameofdeque.at(i) >= nameofdeque.at(i+1){"
but to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/operator_at) takes `size_t` i.e. an index but you're passing an iterator to it. If you want to do it with iterators then change the 4th line to this

```
if (*i >= *(i+1)) {
```

To avoid such confusion, an iterator is usually named `iter` instead of the usual identifier used for a loop index or subscript, `i`.

If you really want to do this without iterators but with index, then you could change the function to

```
int CardDeck::inOrder() {
    for (size_t i = 1u; i < nameofdeque.size(); ++i) {
        if (nameofdeque[i - 1] >= nameofdeque[i]) {  // you cannot do this for the first element, hence the loop's variable starts at 1 to offset this
            return 0;
        }
    }   
    return 1;
 }
```

Comment: Your loop will have out of bound access.

Comment: You did not take into account that the deque size may be 0 :-)

Comment: I did take it into account; it's inherently handled rightly. Notice that `i` will be `0` and the condition `0 < 0` will be `false` thus skipping the `for` and returning `1` i.e. inOrder = true for a single element deque is as expected :)

Comment: nameofdeque.size() - 1 will be -1 in case size is zero. If size is unsigned the result will be the highest value of this unsigned type. 0 is smaller than the highest value of this unsigned type, thus the loop will be entered many many times unless the likely case of segmentation fault will occur.

Comment: Well spotted! Aah, I mistook your comment for size `1` case :) Fixed now!

Answer (score 2):

Iterator is not an index of deque, you use `*i` to access the member it points to.

Answer (score 2):

In you code `i` is an iterator, not an index (integer).
`operator[]` requires index (integer) as an argument.